# How to do an SQL query dependent on username and url in Apache with authz_dbd for require dbd_group, and set group as http header

Tags: apache, authorization, role-based-access-control

I'm having trouble using mod_authz_dbd in Apache to do access control with :

```
require dbd_group
```

I have a Apache reverse proxy, that must do authentication and authorization to let users accessing their projects. Projects need a http header containing group for role-based access control. Currently I would like to authorize users if they have a valid group for a project. I use the following mysql database with my apache server :

```
 ______________     _________________      __________________
|     User     |   | User's project  |    |      Project     | 
|--------------|   |-----------------|    |------------------|
|PK | id       |_  |PK | id          |   _|PK | id           |
|   | username | \_|FK | user_id     |  / |   | url          |
|   | password |   |FK | project_id  |_/  |   | project name |
|______________|   |   | group       |    |__________________|
                   |_________________|
```

The project url is relative url like "/foo".

Each user can work in several projects and can have different group for each,
groups are per project and can take three values :

- admin
- pm for the project manager
- dev for the developers

To implement this, I write in my configuration file :

```
# Get relative url in environment variable.
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=TARGET_URL:$1]
Require dbd-group "admin"
Require dbd-group "pm"
Require dbd-group "dev"
AuthzDBDQuery "SELECT group FROM user, project, users_project WHERE username = %s AND url='%{TARGET_URL}e' AND project.id = users_project.project_id AND user.id = users_project.user_id" 

# Here set the group but how ?
RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Groups" "group"
```

**But I have two problems :**

**first, using environment variables in the SQL query does not work. So, how can I make a query with username and url as parameters in AuthzDBDQuery ?**

**Secondly, how to get group from the AuthzDBDQuery to set it in http header ?**

I also tried with a RewriteMap with dbd and then with prg using python script, but same problem, I did not find how to pass two parameters.

Comment: In my very limited experience, the designers of authorization-by-group features assume a boolean reply that is either "yes, in the named group" or "no, not in the named group" is all anyone could ever want.  I realize that's not much help.

Comment: I think the condition "member of any of these three groups" must be expressed as a single `Require dbd-group` with the three possible values in an Apache expression, also see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html